# regex in sed to replace particular string

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file config.txt which consist of lines like below

```
$ cat config.txt | head -n 3
f03889d9abcb6a16155411bb8e0a34dddb5c8e4c@192.168.3.4:26601
be9d757acee1f5b573ec18d1e056542bc282be23@169.172.56.77:26604
d40ec20a080468fcd5965493d904e4d536cf5767@10.129.101.3:26607

$ cat ip.txt | head -n 3
10.0.4.5
10.3.5.6
10.3.5.8
```

I would like to replace the IP address on config.txt with ip's on ip.txt file respectively

the expected output is

```
f03889d9abcb6a16155411bb8e0a34dddb5c8e4c@10.0.4.5:26601
be9d757acee1f5b573ec18d1e056542bc282be23@10.3.5.6:26604
d40ec20a080468fcd5965493d904e4d536cf5767@10.3.5.8:26607
```

Since the ip's in config file are dynamic, I need to use regex in sed to replace the IP.
for an example:

```
$ echo "f03889d9abcb6a16155411bb8e0a34dddb5c8e4c@192.168.3.4:26601" | sed "s/*@\+:*/*@10.0.4.5:*/g"
```

but its not updating the ip's. I am very new to the regex in scripting. Kindly help!

Comment: Avoid the Useless Use Of Cat (tm) with `head -n3 config.txt`, btw.

Answer (score 3):

Well, *in this case* it is possible to use `sed` and a regex. You could *first join the files* and *then* use regex to shuffle *lines*:

```
paste config.txt ip.txt | sed 's/@[^:]*\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/@\2\1/'
```

Note that `sed` works in the context of *a single line only*. But a regex is not "dynamic", if `the ip's in config file are dynamic` then you should use something "more" then regex, better a full programming language with support for maps and internal state, like `awk` but also `perl` or `python`.

Answer (score 0):

A way using `awk` instead. It first reads `ip.txt` and stores its contents in an array indexed by line number, and then for each line of `config.txt`, replaces the IP address in it with the one from the corresponding line of `ip.txt`:

```sh
$ awk 'FNR==NR { ips[FNR] = $0; next }
       { sub(/@[^:]+:/, "@" ips[FNR] ":"); print }' ip.txt config.txt
f03889d9abcb6a16155411bb8e0a34dddb5c8e4c@10.0.4.5:26601
be9d757acee1f5b573ec18d1e056542bc282be23@10.3.5.6:26604
d40ec20a080468fcd5965493d904e4d536cf5767@10.3.5.8:26607
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
paste -d~ config.txt ip.txt | while IFS="~" read config ip; 
do
echo $config | sed -r "s/([a-z0-9]+)@(([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4})(:[0-9]+)/\1@$ip\4/g";
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure sed answer. I commented it. Put the content to my.sed and call  sed  -n -f my.sed config.txt ip.txt

```
# We concat config.txt and ip.txt to a single line like
# f...c@192.168.3.4:26601|b...3@169.172.56.77:26604|d...7@10.129.101.3:26607|;10.0.4.5;10.3.5.6;10.3.5.8
# the characters "|" and ";" are used as separators
# the records of config.txt are identified by @,
# those of ip.txt the pattern ^[0-9]\(\.[0-9]\)\{3\}

# if it's a config.txt line append "|" and append it to the hold space
/@/ {
    s/$/|/
    H
}
# if it's a ip.txt line put a ";" before it and append it to the hold space
/^[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\{3\}/ {
    s/^/;/
    H
}
# Now the two files are read. We do the replacements at the end of input
$ { 
    x
    # after having deleted all newlines the pattern spaces consists
    # of one line as mentioned above
    s/\n//g
    :b
    # now we replace recursively the ip adress in the first "|"
    # limited column by the ip adress in
    # the first ";" limited column. (:b ist the beginning of the loop) 
    # 1. group: sequence of not | characters ended by @<ip-adress>:<not | characters>
    # 2. group: the characters including the "@"
    # 3. group: part of the ip adress pattern
    # 4. group: the characters from : to "|" (excluded)
    # 5. group: the sequence of not ";" characters followed by ";"
    # 6. group: the replacement ip adress
    # 7. group: part of the replacement ip adress pattern
    # The "," in the replacement replaces the first "|" in order
    # to enable recursion (see 1. group above)

    s/\(\([^|]*@\)[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\{3\}\(:[^|]*\)\)|\([^;]*\);\([0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\{3\}\)/\2\6\4,\5/
    tb
    # replace all , except the last one with newlines
    s/,\(.\)/\n\1/g
    # replace the last ","
    s/,//
    p
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & cat):

```
cat -n ipFile | sed -E 's/\t(.*)/s#@.*:#@\1:#/' | sed -f - configFile
```

Prepend line numbers to the ipFile.

Replace each line in the ipFile by a sed substitution command for an ip address.

Invoke a second application of sed using the configFile as the source and apply the substitution command from the ipFile against each line in the file.

N.B. The `-f` option accepts sed command from a file, in this cast the file is `-` piped through from the previous application of sed.

---

Another solution:

```
paste configFile ipFile | sed -E 's/@.*:(\S*)\t(\S+)/@\2:\1/;/@/!d'
```

This will replace the appended ip address in the configFile.

N.B. If the ipFile has more lines than the configFile the `/@/!d` will make sure the additional lines are not included.